# Redirecting all console messages to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, console, output-redirect

First of all, sorry for the bad grammar and poor English

I'm working on a C# winforms project which simplifies the arguments for another cmd based program.
I am using  process redirect methods, and it kind of works great and all, but...
after around 10 seconds it lags and only outputs the result to the textbox every 15-20 seconds.
I was wondering if there is a way to "flush" the streams buffer.

So far this is some of the code I have (only code that handles the cmd anyhow):

```
Process cmdHorch = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = baseDir + "donich.exe",
        Arguments = startstring,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        ErrorDialog = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
    },
    EnableRaisingEvents = true,
    SynchronizingObject = this
};
cmdHorch.OutputDataReceived += (s, ea) => this.findLine.AppendText(ea.Data + Environment.NewLine);

cmdHorch.Start();
cmdHorch.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

I've tried puzzling around with "cmdHorch.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Flush();" in order to force flush the stream but it failed miserably.. 
I have searched for a couple of days without any luck regarding this buffer issue.

EDIT:
if I run donich.exe with the same parameters as I put into this program it outputs every (at the longest) 2 seconds (a string of minimum of 30 chars)

EDIT (2/1-2015)
the donich.exe spits out about 1600 lines to the console(or redirected to the textbox) the first  second it runs.

Comment: the lag probably has to do with all the string manipulations. Strings are immutable so `.Text` has to be recreated over and over and over.  Windows may also be getting overwhelmed with update messages and skip some as the process goes on.  You might try using a `StringBuilder` to accumulate the text and `.ToString()` to update the control

Comment: I've tested this code in a little WinForms app. I'm calling a very simple cat command as the process (outputting the first 20,000 lines of a Gutenberg Project text file). Everything is working fine - no lag within the 20 seconds the program executes for. Leads me to think the issue isn't in the code you've provided.

Comment: Also, I can't believe that TextBox.AppendText wouldn't implement some form of buffering as per StringBuilder. The only string construction issue is in the `ea.Data + Environment.NewLine` call, which can be replaced with `string.Format("{0}{1}", ea.Data, Environment.NewLine)`.

Comment: @magos  actually, `AppendText` may aggravate any string issue since it appends to `SelectedText` which in turn involves `.SubString` swapping

Comment: sorry for the late response, busy holidays. (Thanks for the corrections)
@Plutonix but if i use the stringbuilder, wouldn't i run into problems with getting the output "live" from the redirect? or?